# Merge multiple records with the same ID

Tags: arcpy

I have a table that looks like the following

```
ID    Address                      Date
1     11 abc road                  19/03/2018
2     11 def road                  20/03/2018
2     11 def road                  21/03/2018
3     11 qaz road                  25/03/2018
4     11 zxc road                  26/03/2018
4     11 zxc road                  27/03/2018
6     11 qwe road                  18/03/2018
6     11 qwe road                  19/03/2018
6     11 qwe road                  20/03/2018
```

What I would like to do, is to merge all the rows that have the same id, into one record but merge the differing dates into that same record aswell.

So the final table would look like

```
ID    Address                Date
1     11 abc road            19/03/2018
2     11 def road            20/03/2018, 21/03/2018
3     11 qaz road            19/03/2018
4     11 zxc road            26/03/2018, 27/03/2018
6     11 qwe road            18/03/2018, 19/03/2018, 20/03/2018
```

What is the best pythonic way of achieving this?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify whether this was just a table or has geometry, but this strategy would work for both:
1. Add a new field to hold the concatenated dates
2. Populate this field:

```
# Make a dictionary to hold the "merged' dates
addressDict = {row[0]: [] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor('mylayer', ['Date'])}

# Populate the dictionary with the merged dates
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor('mylayer', ['Address', 'Date']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        addressDict[row[0]].append(row[1])

# Add this to a new merged date field (adding field not shown here)
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor('mylayer', ['Address', 'Date', 'MyMergedDates']) as ucursor:
    for row in ucursor:
        row[2] = ', '.join([str(n) for n in addressDict[row[0]]])
        ucursor.updateRow(row)
```

3. Use the normal merge tool